# How do I colonize additional planets?

Tags: adventure-capitalist

Are there other places you can colonize besides the moon and Mars in AdVenture Capitalist, such as Venus, Mercury, Pluto, other moons or asteroids within the Solar System?

I went to the [wiki](http://adventure-capitalist.wikia.com/wiki/Mission_control), but there doesn't seem to be any discussion on additional colonizable locations.

Comment: Currently, there are no more planets.  Speculation about future plans for games is off-topic here.  That said, I feel like such a thing would have been announced by now given how long the game has been out.

Comment: @GnomeSlice - That would make a good answer,  now that the speculative part has been removed :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only available places to colonize are the Moon and Mars. No [official news](https://steamcommunity.com/app/346900/discussions/0/523898291494376045/) has yet been released about future planets after the release of Mars. [All updates](https://steamcommunity.com/app/346900/allnews/) since, are about events and more ways to have you invest your real money into the game. This question has been [asked](https://steamcommunity.com/app/346900/discussions/0/527273452876005407/) on the internet before and people even [speculate](https://www.kongregate.com/forums/4721-general/topics/534858-yroehts-predictions-for-adventure-capitalist) about the road map of Adventure Capitalist, including different planets.

So the answer to the question "How do I colonize additional planets?" is: You don't, because they do not exist.